# How to get the class name by a substring?

Tags: jquery

I have a link with classes like this:

```
<a class="btn red relevant participant-1 training_id-1 state-1" href="#">
```

I need to read the 'id' numbers for a later action with ajax posts.
How can I catch from class 'participant-1' the number '1'?

I tried with

```
var classList = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
```

but my class names will have a different order from time to time. Therefore I would need to catch them by part of their names.

Does anyone has an idea how to do that?

Comment: That data in classes should probably be in `data-` attributes. I imagine they are content related and not just styling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use **[`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)** attributes instead.

So first set the `data-id` attribute like :

```
$('selector').data('id','value');
```

The HTML so will looks like :

```
<a class="btn red relevant participant state" data-id='1' href="#">
```

Then in your js just use the jQuery method **[`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** :

```
var id = $(this).data('id');
```

Hope this help.

Comment: how can I set a new value to $(this).data('id')?

Comment: great! last question: After my ajax stuff I need to change some class names as well as change the data-state to a new number. I tried 'console.log($(this).data('state'));' but inside my ajax post action I can get the item...